# How to use jQuery to properly set the height of a responsive gallery

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, gallery

We have a basic fade-based jQuery gallery set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/k1x5wkbs/

**The height requirements are:**

1. Set height of `.gallery` to height of image inside `.gallery-item`
2. If gallery is inside `.hero`, set height of `.gallery` to height of `.hero`
3. If window width is below 500px, set height of the `.hero` gallery to the image inside `.gallery-item`
4. Have the height calculated on page load and window resize

**Problems:**

1. At certain window widths, the second gallery's height is not calculated correctly (note gap underneath it or the way it covers the text below - either on page load or window resize)
2. At widths under 500, `.hero` gallery height is incorrectly calculated (it should always be a square under 500px with no gap under it)
3. What is the best way to optimise and integrate the window resize event?

This is our very first attempt at a jQuery function so any additional suggestions for organising/optimising the code would be most welcome.

Cheers

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got some help – some of the layout had to be moved to CSS and a new jQuery plugin written.

Although it's a simple layout from a design point of view, it's actually surprising painful to create in CSS (as usual!).

`.hero-image` and `.hero-text` required positioning context changes because those elements specify and define the container size (the gallery is always 100% of its container.)

```
.hero {
  position:relative;
}
.hero-text {
  position:relative;
}
.hero-image{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Anyway, it means that the gallery can't have a it's height set by simply passing a class to it - CSS requires to be modified which is a shame.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/fkz7bb6r/5/